# Does a piecewise rational/irrational defined function have a bound on its integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$f(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> x/3 &\mbox{if $x$ is rational,}\\
> x/2 &\mbox{if $x$ is irrational.}
> \end{array}\right.$$

Suppose that $f$ is my function, can I say that the integral of this function between $0$ and any positive number is greater than the integral of $x/3$? I want a good reason why I can't put a lower bound on this integral if the answer is no, since it clearly appears to have an upper and lower bound to it.

Comment: You seem to be making some mistake while writing the part in blue. Please check that. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-referenceyou

Comment: If you integrate wrt the Lebesgue measure, the integral of $f$ is equal to the integral of $x/2$, since the rational numbers are a set of measure zero.

Comment: What definition of an integral are you using? Because the answer is very different if you use a Riemann integral (i.e. summing up a lot of rectangles approximating $f$) or a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want a good reason why I can't put a lower bound on this integral if the answer is no, since it clearly appears to have an upper and lower bound to it.

The reason is that there *is* no such (Riemann) integral. Since every interval has both rational and irrational numbers in it, we know
\begin{align*}
    U(f,P) &= U(x/2,P) \\
    L(f,P) &= L(x/3,P)
\end{align*}
for every partition $P$ of an interval $[a,b]$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
    \inf_P U(f,P) = \inf_P U(x/2,P) = \int_a^b (x/3)\,dx \\
    \sup_P L(f,P) = \sup_P L(x/3,P) = \int_a^b (x/2)\,dx
\end{align*}
Since the two on the right are different, $f$ is not integrable on $[a,b]$.

@sranthrop points out that there is a different answer when using the Lebesgue integral.  In that theory we can partition sets into subsets that are not intervals.  For instance, the interval $[a,b]$ can be partitioned into the rational elements (call this set $E$) and irrational elements ($E'$).  Since $E$ is of measure zero,
$$
\int\limits_{[a,b]} f\,d\mu = \int\limits_E f\,d\mu + \int\limits_{E'} f\,d\mu 
= \int\limits_{E'} f\,d\mu = \int_a^b (x/2)\,dx
$$

Comment: So does this mean Riemann integrals are somehow naive or incorrect? I guess to me I think of objects in math as being invariant in a sense, and if we were to completely throw away all definitions we could still rediscover a true definition again from the the situation. I guess a better question is, what circumstances would cause me to view this integral as either Riemann or Lebesgue other than just the arbitrary way I happen to feel today or tomorrow?

Comment: @Kainui You seem to be a [platonist](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism/). Nothing wrong with that, but there are different views. Answering your question, when you see the number $0$, how do you know whether it is the traditional number $0$ or $0$ in some weird vector space? My point being that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are different integrals which happen to use the same symbol. Context will dictate which one you're working with. This is something that should be clarified *a priori*. N.B.: Whenever the riemann-integral exists, so does the Lebesgue integral and they coincide.

Comment: @Kainui Given the choice, I would say riemann integrals are naive rather than incorrect.  To say you want to throw away all the definitions and recover a true one leads to some inconsistencies. For instance, when you try to recover the measure of a set of numbers from its desired properties you are inevitably led to non-measurable sets.